# Interaction with peer- reviewer

Tags: publications, research-process, peer-review

I received a peer review of my research paper. I answered the question arises there in comments. I didn't find such details of the reviewer to give information about some question arises in peer review.

> Is there a way to communicate with peer reviewer?

Comment: Through the editor/journal.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, normally via the editor.

This is part of the point of blind reviews: to control the exchange and the editor is the "referee" to decide when the purpose is achieved.

Comment: how we get an editor?

Comment: You have one, when you submitted your paper to the journal, it went to an editor or equivalent. Contact the journal you submitted to.